How to run "ping" command from within Laravel Sail application
I'm working with Laravel 11 and need to programmatically execute the "ping" command and get the result. I'm using Laravel Sail. But when I attempt to use the Process facade I get an error:

"sh: 1: ping: not found
" // app/Livewire/Site/Forms/Tools/ToolForm.php:48

$result = Process::run('ping -c 3 google.com');

dd($result->errorOutput());

How can I achieve this?

Did you check whether ping is installed on the system you want to use it on?

It's using Laravel Sail

That is because ping is not installed in the container. In your docker-compose.yml you have something like
        build:
           context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3
           dockerfile: Dockerfile

Copy the Dockerfile in the root directory of your project and ajust the path, then add the ping-utils installation command
RUN apt-get update \
&& mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
&& apt-get install -y iputils-ping \


I tried going into the container directly using sail root-shell and running apt-get install -y iputils-ping and the package iputils-ping can't be found. The sail:publish command publishes the entire docker file. I'd ideally prefer not to publish the entire thing for the sake of one package? Is there another way around this. Additionally, that package can't be found?

Weird, it's working on my side. I don't see any other workaround. Doing it manually by going inside the container is not a viable option.

I don't think there is any harm in releasing the package for the sake of just one thing. All sail:publish does is copy the dockerfile etc. files in the vendor directory to the root directory and change the path in docker-compose.yml accordingly. It does not harm other than increasing the number of files in your project. Also, remember that sail is not for production. In my opinion, all the time spent on the development environment itself is time stolen from the development process.
